# How to import _RetryDict from botocore-stubs?

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, boto3

I need to import `_RetryDict` from botocore-stubs in order to satisfy mypy for the following code:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
from botocore.config import Config

@dataclass
class COMMON_CONSTANTS:
    region = "eu-west-1"
    retry_config = {
        'max_attempts': 10,
        'mode': 'adaptive',
    }

conf = Config(retries=COMMON_CONSTANTS.retry_config)
```

I have tried `from botocore.stubs import _RetryConfig`, etc., but nothing seems to work?

https://github.com/search?q=repo%3Ayoutype%2Fbotocore-stubs%20_RetryDict&type=code